# Tracking a file over time

Tags: python, file, file-io, filesystems

My idea is to track a specific file on a file-system over time between two points in time, `T1` and `T2`. The emphasis here lies on looking at a file as a unique entity on a file-system. One that can change in data and attributes but still maintain its unique identity.

The ultimate goal is to determine whether or not the data of a file has (unwillingly) changed between `T1` and `T2` by capturing and recording the data-hash and creation/modification attributes of the file at `T1` and comparing them with the equivalents at `T2`. If all attributes are unchanged but the hash doesn't validate we can say that there is a problem. In all other cases we might be willing to say that a changed hash is the result of a modification and an unchanged hash and unchanged modification-attribute the result of no change on the file(data) at all.

Now, there are several ways to refer to a file and corresponding drawbacks:

- *The path to the file*: However, if the file is moved to a different location this method fails.
- *A data-hash of the file-data*: Would allow a file, or rather (a) pointer to the file-data on disk, to be found, even if the pointer has been moved to a different directory, but the data cannot change or this method fails as well.

My idea is to retrieve a fileId for that specific file at `T1` to track the file at `T2`, even if it has changed its location so it doesn't need to be looked at as a *new* file.

I am aware of two methods pywin offers. `win32file.GetFileInformationByHandle()` and `win32file.GetFileInformationByHandleEx()`, but they obviously are restricted to specific file-systems, break cross-platform-compatibility and sway away from a universal approach to track the file.

My question is simple: Are there any other ideas/theories to track a file, ideally accross platforms/FSs?

Any brainstormed food for thought is welcome!

Comment: How about taking MD5 hash of file contents. And checking md5 hashes over different time instances?

Comment: On linux file systems (`ext` I guess), you have inodes which if I'm not mistaken will remain the same across file moves. On windows, however... I'm not sure. It's a good question. You might have to write some platform-specific code and just cover all your bases.

Comment: @SidharthShah: He covered that. If the file moves *and* is modified between T1 and T2 you're screwed. Hash will differ; you won't be able to find the file again.

Comment: you might have to do some kernel-level stuff, hook into whatever it is that moves files and modifies them and keep a log somewhere

Comment: @Mark: Great, that sounds like an equivalent to the fileIndices on NTFS/FAT(?): `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` allows you to retrieve a `nFileIndexLow` and `nFileIndexHigh` which uniquely identifies a file in combination with the `VolumeSerialNumber` on a single closed system. Tracking ability would be ideal to eliminate the manual task of verifying that a file in location A at `T1` is the same as the one in location B at `T1`, which would, especially on larger file-trees, an unrealistic approach.

Comment: @Claudiu: Okay, yes that is an alternative I have thought of before but most likely would exceed the scope of Python, which I am currently using primarily and require a service running in the background at all time. Plus, if executed on a whole file-system (which is the potential idea) it might result in a considerable slow-down. But an idea and possible option nonetheless, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really feasible in general, because the idea of file identity is an illusion (similar to the illusion of physical identity, but this isn't a philosophy forum).

1. You cannot track identity using file contents, because contents change.
2. You cannot track by any other properties attached to the file, because many file editors will save changes by deleting the old file and creating a new one.

Version control systems handle this in three ways:

1. (CVS) Don't track move operations.
2. (Subversion) Track move operations manually.
3. (Git) Use a heuristic to label operations as "move" operations based on changes to the contents of a file (e.g., if a new file differs from an existing file by less than 50%, then it's labeled as a copy).

Things like inode numbers are **not** stable and not to be trusted.  Here, you can see that editing a file with Vim will change the inode number, which we can examine with `stat -f %i`:

```
$ touch file.txt
$ stat -f %i file.txt
4828200
$ vim file.txt
...make changes to file.txt...
$ stat -f %i file.txt 
4828218
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks. A good and actually very obvious point I didn't consider is the fact that many applications re-write a file's data into a new file deleting the former. Interesting to see how other version-control systems handle this, I will look into Git's heuristic approach and see if that can be applied to arbitrary data, text as well as binary. Trusting and relying on file IDs/inodes seemed risky from the very beginning.